# What to use Bitnami,Phpfog or direct aws for Website hosting

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, bitnami

I from past few weeks I have been trying to explore AWS but all I could gather is that it is a VM where you install the required software, your website and you are up and running.But when it comes to choosing right product for myself I couldnt make any break through.

Also, I explored bitnami and PHPFog, but couldnt really get the difference between three, obviously bitnami and phpfog are using AWS but how are they making things better for a webadmin?

I have always used cpannel for hosting and while exploring cloud env I feel it is bit complicated to use.

Also there are so many products in AWS if I have to host a website which is high on data and too many users, what configuration should i choose and what product. If someone can point me to a tutorial which will explain things step by step it will be really helpfull

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm the product manager from PHP Fog. The question  you are asking is something I've been asked a number of times before. I recently posted a blog article explaining the difference between Traditional hosting and Platform-as-a-Service like PHP Fog.

http://teamblog.phpfog.com/traditional-vs-paas-hosting/

AWS, while it does provide hosting, it is at the "Infrastructure-as-a-Service" level. This basically means you'll be responsible for setting up Apache, PHP, NGinx, etc. In the end you will basically have a dedicated server for your application; however, you will not be able to scale it very easily. If you do want to scale it, you will need to a whole lot of work.

Bitnami, provides you with additional functionality you don't get with AWS, like easier deployment. So while it is built on top of AWS, you no longer have to do all the crazy configuration work to get started. However, Bitnami is very limiting. Notice that you have to pay quite a bit, and it doesn't even include the charges for AWS. You also have to commit to a given plan and pay a fixed monthly amount just to use the service, and on top of that you will still need to pay for the servers on AWS.

PHP Fog, provide a cloud based infrastructure so you get scalability and reliability. We also make it very easy to get started. Pricing is based on usage. So if you run your application on one server, you only pay for that. If you need to scale your application to 50 servers, you'll pay for that. You can of course scale back too and pay only for what you used. We also provide a free account on shared hosting. You can use this as much as you want, and when you are ready, you can migrate your application to a dedicated server (or servers).

Comment: I want to correct you here, our prices are quite reasonable, and in fact cheaper than PHPFog. As an example, our developer plan is FREE for one year and includes a dedicated micro instance for free. Compare this to PHPfog entry level plan which is free for 6 months and in a shared server. For paid plans, a micro in your Silver Cloud is $29 so having 3 servers is going to be $87. The same setup in our platform costs $72 ($48 Amazon charges + $24 for BitNami) or about $15 cheaper. So, there are pros and cons for BitNami when compared to PHP Fog, but pricing is definitely not one of them.